# Reports API: Customer Usage – Google+ Parameters - strange report values

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-hangouts

I need to create a detailed reports about Google Hangout usage including below:

- Total sessions (hangouts) per month
- Total minutes per month
- Total attendees
- Average attendee number per hangout
- Average duration per hangout
- Number of 1:1 hangouts
- Number of hangouts including external phone invite
- Total data exchanged in MB
- Average data exchanged in MB

I have found that [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/) allow to get customer usage for Google+ and it includes these three parameters:

- num_video_calls
- total_video_call_minutes
- num_video_conferences

How this values are calculated? I have prepared sample report for my client domain and the results does not fit to parameters explanation on https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/usage-ref-appendix-a/customers-gplus.

Below sample report:

```
Hangout usage report for ***.com by a day
Date            | num_video_calls | num_video_conferences | total_video_call_minutes 

2014-06-30      | 46              | 0                     | 855            
2014-06-29      | 6               | 0                     | 104            
2014-06-28      | 12              | 0                     | 271            
2014-06-27      | 92              | 0                     | 1186           
2014-06-26      | 77              | 38                    | 783            
2014-06-25      | 21              | 16                    | 237            
2014-06-24      | 41              | 24                    | 674            
2014-06-23      | 31              | 23                    | 135            
2014-06-22      | 6               | 6                     | 43             
2014-06-21      | 2               | 2                     | 2              
2014-06-20      | 7               | 7                     | 32             
2014-06-19      | 16              | 11                    | 143            
2014-06-18      | 28              | 20                    | 311            
2014-06-17      | 16              | 11                    | 210            
2014-06-16      | 30              | 23                    | 458            
2014-06-15      | 1               | 1                     | 0              
2014-06-14      | 2               | 1                     | 1
```

I don't understand report e.g. for days:

- 2014-06-30 - there was 46 video calls but 0 video conferences. Is
  that possible or is that ok?
- 2014-06-22 - video calls are equals to
  video conferences. Is that possible or is that ok?
- 2014-06-15 -
  there are 1 video call and 1 video conference but 0 minutes. Could
  this happen?

Another questions:

1. What are video calls and what are video conferences? What are the diferrences? And how they are related to a video hangout? 
   Above report do not confirm note from google that *"Note: Two people participating in a video hangout is counted as 1 video conference and 2 video calls."*
2. How are total minutes calculated? Assume we have one hangout in a report day with 3 attendees and meeting take 5 minutes. What will show *total_video_call_minutes* for this hangout? 5 minutes or 3x5=15 minutes? This is not clear from documentation.
3. Can I somehow find/calc other statistics mentioned above e.g. number of 1:1 hangouts, hangouts with external phone invite...?

Thanks

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this ? I have a similar requirement